# Reuse a data object model across multiple requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Newbie to the whole ASP.Net conundrum !!

So I have a set of Web API's (Actions) in a controller which will be called in succession to each other from the client. All the API's depend on a data model object fetched from the database. Right now I have a DAO layer which fetches this data and transparently caches it. So there is no immediate issue as there is no round trip to database for each API call. But the DAO layer is maintained by a different team and makes no guarantee that the cache will continue to exist or it's behaviour won't change.

Now the properties or attributes of the model object would change but not too often. So If I refer the API calls made in succession from a client as a bundle, then I can safely assume that the bundle can actually query this data once and use it without having to worry about change in value. How can I achieve this ? Is there a design pattern somewhere in ASP.Net world which I can use ? What I would like is to fetch this value at a periodic interval and refresh it in case one of the API calls failed indicating the underlying values have changed.

Comment: You will need to create [session state](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) for each "bundle."  That means ditching statelessness (which will hurt your performance) and you need to define when a session begins and when it ends, i.e. find some way for the program to detect the beginning and end of a "bundle," and to detect (and exclude) when transactions are received from a different client during the same time period.  Does the service require authentication?

Comment: Yeah the service needs Authentication. Basically all API calls will be authenticated with a session token

Answer (score 0):

There are a few techniques that might be used. First of all, is there a reason for the need of a second cache, because your Data Access Layer already has it, right?

You can place a cache on the Web API response level by using a third party library called [Strathweb.CacheOutput](https://github.com/filipw/Strathweb.CacheOutput), and:

> CacheOutput will take care of server side caching and set the appropriate client side (response) headers for you.

You can also cache the data from your data access layer by using a more manual approach by using the *MemoryCache* from *System.Runtime.Caching*.

Depending on what's the infrastructure available, distributed caches like *Cassandra* or *Redis* may be the best choice.